# Issue with SQL subquery, getting null values

Tags: sql

I have a query similar to given below. When I run the individual queries, they work but when ran together I am getting null values for the last part as given in the output table. am I doing something wrong?

```
WITH TRAIN AS 
(
SELECT
train.number AS Train#,
train.date AS Date
FROM train.db AS train
WHERE train.date = '2022-04-15'
),
COACH AS
(
SELECT
coach.number,
coach.train_nbr,
coach.train_dt
FROM coach.db as coach
WHERE coach.train_dt = '2022-04-15'
AND coach.train_nbr IN (SELECT DISTINCT train.number FROM TRAIN) 
),
SEAT AS 
(
seat.coach_nbr AS Coach#,
seat.number AS Seat#
FROM seat.db AS seat
WHERE seat.train_dt = '2022-04-15' 
AND seat.coach_nbr IN (SELECT DISTINCT coach.number FROM COACH)
)
SELECT
TRAIN.*,
SEAT.*
FROM TRAIN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COACH ON TRAIN.number = COACH.train_nbr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SEAT ON COACH.number = SEAT.coach_nbr
```

Output I am getting is attached. [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNklf.jpg)

Comment: Your second LEFT OUTER JOIN didn't find any rows in `SEAT` matching your ON-condition. It's impossible to guess why not without looking at your data.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `INNER JOIN`, to understand the behavior of your sentence over your data, it seems to be a problem in your seccond `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as commented by [O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones), looks like the values of your `SEAT` table doesn't match with the values in `COACH`. Overall is hard to know what are going without looking at your data.

Answer (score 0):

The query seems overly complex. I don't understand the need to use CTEs here (`with` clause). For example the filtering for seats that have `coach_nbr` value in `COACH` table is something that is automatically done for you when using `left join`.

It looks as if the data model is flawed. I don't understand how the seats in a coach can differ by date so I suppose `train_dt` should not be a column in your `SEAT` table.

Anyhow I suppose this query should produce the required output for the tables as they are now:

```
select
    train.number as Train#,
    train.date as Date,
    seat.coach_nbr as Coach#,
    seat.number as Seat#
from
    train.db as train
    left join coach.db as coach on coach.train_nbr = train.number and coach.train_dt = train.date
    left join seat.db as seat on seat.coach_nbr = coach.number and seat.train_dt = train.date
where
    train.date = '2022-04-15'
;
```